# At the end of the Hobbit, if Strider was already a Ranger, how come he still looks that young in Fellowship of the Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

I didn't read the books (obviously), so I am kind of confused. Do Men live that long in Tolkien's world? I know Gandalf is supposedly an old-timer as well, but he's a wizard so it kind of doesn't count :D

Comment: The movies altered the timeline.  The below answer is correct, but Arargorn should not be a ranger during or immediately after the Hobbit (he should be a 10 year old kid).

Comment: Can't add an answer anymore, but if you're referring to the line mentioning him at the end of Episode III, the movies indeed messed with the timeline. The book's 17-year gap between Bilbo's party and Frodo leaving the Shire didn't happen, so in movie time the bulk of LotR occurs "only" 60 years after The Hobbit. That would put Aragorn at age 27-28 at the time of this reference, plenty old enough to have been a reputable Ranger.

Answer (score 4):

The high men, who befriended the elves in the First Age and fought against the first dark lord Morgoth, were gifted with long lives.  Aragorn (who was descended from the royal house of the high men) was 88 when he was crowned king, and he lived for a further 122 years after that.  That was a fairly typical lifespan for a pureblooded man of the West in the Third Age, although his ancestors had lived to even greater ages.  Elros (Elrond's twin brother, who opted to be a man rather than an elf) lived to the age of 500, ruling as the first king of Numenor for 442 years.

Other men did not enjoy these extremely long lifespans.  By the end of the Third Age, even in the realm of Gondor, most people of Numenorean descent had interbred extensively with the low men, shortening their lifespans.  It is noted in *The Return of the King* that even living past 100 was growing uncommon except among the more pureblooded Gondorian nobility.